# How to shutdown Google App Engine's local dev server from the command line?

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-eclipse-plugin

I have run the local GAE app server (`dev_appserver.py`) from Eclipse and then Eclipse crashed. So I had to kill Eclipse and restart it. However, when Eclipse restarted, it lost connection to the still running GAE server and I cannot figure how to shut it down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to kill the process of the devserver. This is os dependent. On linux use:

```
ps aux| grep java 
kill -9 <process id>
```

On windows you can use `tasklist` and `taskkill`.

Comment: no, just a particular one. that's why I wrote `<process id>`.

Comment: I see. On linux, you will see the path of the instance but you don't see that on windows tho. Still, I feel like it is not a proper method.

Answer (score 1):

I found (one Windows XP) that if I started the local server using ant, and then tried to kill it with ^C, it wouldn't kill JAVA.EXE,

but when I start the server using a small batch file reading "%appEngine_home%\bin\dev_appserver.cmd war", when I press ^C it kills it.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late but just for future viewers of this question, in Windows you can press ctrl + c to terminate Dev App Server from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX this can be achieved by explicitly naming the process and using killall within the terminal, e.g.:

```
killall python /YOUR_PATH_TO_THE_SERVER_RUNTIME/dev_appserver.py
```

Answer (score 0):

open your task manager, There will be a task (for me it's _go_app) and if you end that, it ends the server, going to the URL the response will be that "the server suddenly stopped". Look for the python apps running, if you are still stuck in bash and can't use your shell, you can close those python tasks to get access to your shell, or you can try ctrl + \ which worked for me.[image]